# What meaning does "hardly" impose in this context?

Tags: meaning

"The jury was hardly moved by the man’s plea that his loneliness was an extenuating factor in his crime of dognapping a prized pooch"

What did it end with? was the jury finally moved? or not at all?

Comment: Did you look the word up in a dictionary? It's hard to answer properly unless we know what you already understand.

Comment: What word? I posted the question to understand the sentence. I don't understand it a priori.

Comment: What do you mean, "what word?" I think Daniel means the word *you are asking about*.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here, hardly means "barely or not at all," so the jury was not moved.

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned in another answer, *hardly* means barely (or, per [wiktionary](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/hardly#Adverb), “Barely, only just, almost not”).

Note that saying “The jury was hardly moved” sounds unnatural to me; I'd expect phrases like “The jury was little moved” or “The jury was barely moved” to be used more commonly.